# How to make custom theme options for a client

Tags: ghost-blog

I am currently making a custom theme, but I ran into an issue. How does one create custom options for Ghost blog users to change the color of certain elements on the page? For a broad general question: How does one make custom options in the first place? For now, the default options on a typical Ghost theme is changing the logo and banner image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Ghost is currently not supporting many customization features. That may be solved in the next release(0.5.*) when the plugin API comes in. 
Right now you can write your your style sheets in some prepossessing language like SASS and put all your customizations into a variables.sass file and ask your users to customize that file and compile it.

Comment: Nowadays 0.7.5. is released, but look like no improvement on this topic has arrived.